# Efficient way to find dictionaries of sets has zero intersection in python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

say we have following dicts:

```py
d1 = {"a": {1, 2, 3}, "b": {2}}
d2 = {"a": {1, 2}, "b": {2, 3, 4}}
d3 = {"a": {5}, "b": {1, 5}}
```

I would need to quickly determine `True` or `False` on whether it exist dictionary that has member that doesn't intersect with others. In above example, it will return False, because `d3` has extra elements on `a` and `b`.

I have following solution, which basically will loop through the dictionary, and key, value pairs and insert the `intersection` value to a result dictionary.

```py
    def _check_conflict(ds):
        all_items = {}
        for d in ds:
            for key, value in d.items():
                if key in all_items:
                    existing_item = all_items[key]
                    item_intersection = existing_item & value
                    if len(item_intersection) == 0:
                        return False
                    all_items[key] = item_intersection
                else:
                    all_items[key] = value
        return True
```

and it's running pretty slow. Is there other way to speed it up?

I did realize that we can get the intersections of keys of those dicts and iterate only those keys, but it's not possible when we have > 2 dicts.

Comment: Would like to confirm a couple of stuff: 
1. do you want to find intersections of sets with keys "a" and "b" inside your d1,d2 and d3 dictionaries?
2. if yes to above the intersection between sets has an inbuilt function: intersection() ,  you could try that

Comment: yes that's a solution, but wouldn't it be slower because it's doing intersection of a certain key on every dictionary? We'll want to return False straight away on say between `d1` and `d2`, and not do intersection on `d1`, `d2` and `d3`.

Comment: What is ds in comparison with d1, d2, and d3?